# Как постоянно возвращать аутентифицированного юзера

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

Есть страницы на Freemarker, возможно ли возвращать аутентифицированного юзера постоянно, без написания в каждом методе `@AuthenticationPrincipal Owner userAuth` `model.addAttribute("userAuth", userAuth);`

```
@GetMapping
public String getAll(@AuthenticationPrincipal Owner userAuth, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userAuth", userAuth);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте свой HandlerInterceptor приблизительно такой:

```
public class PrincipalToModelInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response,
       Object handler, 
       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
       Object principal = 
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();    
       // возможно захотите проверить principal на null перед добавлением 
       // это в случае, если нет аутентифицированного пользователя
       modelAndView.addObject("userAuth", principal);
    }
}
```

Далее нужно добавить interceptor в конфигурацию. Например, в класс конфигурации, который реализует `WebMvcConfigurer` :

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new PrincipalToModelInterceptor());
}
```